# How to give multiple input at each time step of a sequential data to a recurrent neural network using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose i am having a data set with: number of observations = 1000, each observation is a sequence of fixed length = 10(lets say), and each point in the sequence having 2 features(numerical). how we can input such data to an rnn in tensorflow ?
Any small suggestions also accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, Your dataset is 1000x10x2

which looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np

data=np.random.randint(0,10,[1000,10,2])
```

Now as you said your sequence is fixed size so you don't need padding , now you have to just decide batch_size and then iterations

suppose batch size is 5:

```
batch_size=5
iterations=int(len(train_dataset)//batch_size)
```

Now feed your input to tensorflow lstm cell , your model would be something like this:

Here is example without batch size,

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

data=np.random.randint(0,10,[1000,10,2])
input_x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1000,10,2])

with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:
    cell=rnn.LSTMCell(150)
    model=tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,inputs=input_x,dtype=tf.float32)

    output_,(fs,fc)=model



with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output = sess.run(model, feed_dict={input_x: data})

    print(output)
```

if you want to use batch then you have to either reshape data for LSTM or you have to use embedding, because LSTM takes rank 3